Why is there no synchronization in Photon pun in unity?
I decided to add multiplayer to my game using photon pun, but for some reason not two players (that is, "computers") synchronize, but just the player synchronizes with himself, what could be the problem?
I can't even figure out what to do in such a situation

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
